# GPIO voltage drop

Tags: voltage, resistance, gpio

I have the following problem. I have a 3 V line that comes from an electronic drums controller that goes into a pedal through a mono cable (TS). The tip has +3 V and the sleeve is GND 0 V. When I press the pedal the these wires get shorted and the controller detects the voltage drop to trigger a sound. The pedal has it's own resistance which causes the 3 V line to go down at around 2.87 V. Now I want to connect a second pedal on the same line using an Y cable. Because of that the voltage drops under 2.7 V which makes the controller to not detect the voltage drop when I press the pedal and does not trigger any sound. I need to add some circuit that can boost the voltage to overcome the second pedal voltage drop. I tried a DC booster but didn't seem to work. I used a cheap circuit from AliExpress which I connected 3 V to + and GND to -. I also tried with a 3 V battery in series but this kind of reversed the detection, meaning that it would trigger when I would release the pedal, not when I pressed it. Please help!

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but sounds like internal pull-up with too high trigger point. Open it up and reverse the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relay(to switch the GPIO input) driven from multiple pedals wired in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flL2Li.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you expand this answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are cheap relay modules available that should work for your application, for example [3.3V Relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004189731241.html?src=google&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=708-803-3821&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=19374042898&albag=&trgt=&crea=en1005004189731241&netw=x&device=c&albpg=&albpd=en1005004189731241&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-_mvBhDwARIsAA-Q0Q4sfPMfkARAL8G2iFJTEZok2p6mLICjmcudUd_tEXva724UNtJoXLUaAipQEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&aff_fcid=d38d8815852241b2b0029bf8359316a4-1711210476819-07847-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=d38d8815852241b2b0029bf8359316a4-1711210476819-07847-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=7895fdda5cb14e2cb912e8e2655ebbbf&afSmartRedirect=y#nav-specification). Wire the relays in parallel. If pressing a switch turns off the relay instead of operating the relay then use the NC (Normally Closed) contacts instead ot the NO (Normally Open) contacts.